# How do I shut down detected virtual machines on Mac OS?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I haven't used VirtualBox probably since 2016 and today I dusted it off and of course I needed to install an updated version, but I soon got this message:

> The installer has detected running virtual machines. Please shut down
>   all running VirtualBox machines and then restart the installation.

What is a streamlined bash/zsh commands I could run on terminal find out what virtual machines are running and to shut them down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the commands are:

`VBoxManage list vms`

And to unregister and delete them:

`VBoxManage unregistervm --delete <uuid>`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same situation and ran the previously posted commands but no vm was running.

> Apparently the commands are:
>
> `VBoxManage list vms`
>
> And to unregister and delete them:
>
> `VBoxManage unregistervm --delete <uuid>`

Turns out I had to delete my current `VirtualBox.app` in my Applications then I was able to run the new installation.